# Integration angular 2.0 with Spring mvc

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, angular

I try to connect back-end java application with angular 2.0 front-end

Application structure:

```
src/main/java/com.example/
                               config/MvcConfig.java
                               controllers/HomeController.java
                                          /simpleResponseProducer.java
src/main/resources/
                               application.properties
                               js/helloJS.js
src/main/WEB-INF/jsp/
                               home.jsp
```

HomeController.java

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String home(){
        return "home";
    }
}
```

home.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/zone.js/0.6.12/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/reflect-metadata/0.1.3/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/systemjs/0.19.27/dist/system.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/helloJS.js"></script>
    <title>HOME_ANGULAR</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

MvcConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example")
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/webjars/**")) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
        }
        if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/js/**")) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/js/");
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver internalViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        viewResolver.setOrder(1);
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

Should HomeController return String "home"? 
Is this return statement, points to home.jsp file?
I would like to go to the loclahost:9900/home and see home.jsp
Is it correct way to do that?

How should i run this? As springBootAplication?

When i try to display "localhost:9900/home" i get:

No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'

i have feeling that i do logical mistake.

Comment: have you tried `localhost:9900/#/home`? The pound sign should prohibit the page from navigating a different url or access point on your server, it just updates `window.location` that Angular can use to find which template would you like to have rendered.

Comment: localhost:9900/#/home gives me 404 becouse i do not have mapping for localhost:9900/. The url adress is correct. The problem is that somehow i do not have mapping to /WEB-INF/jsp/error.jsp